# How many active pilots are there in the US? How many are women?

Tags: usa, faa, pilot-certification

How many active pilots are there in the US?  Also, how many active flight instructors are there?  Out of all of active pilots and flight instructors how many are women?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [FAA](https://www.faa.gov/data_research/aviation_data_statistics/civil_airmen_statistics/), as of December 31, 2016, there are:

**584,361 Active pilots** (39,187 are Women pilots, or about 7%)

**104,382 Flight Instructors** (6,848 are Women Flight Instructors, or about 7%)

The ratio of female instructors to female active pilots is virtually the same as for males.

[image]

Comment: It's interesting that the percentage of active pilots who are women and flight instructors who are women stay the same.  I wonder if that's true of women in most highly-skilled highly-certified technical fields.